# Writing my own Provider Class in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, membership-provider, dataprovider

Note: I DON't want to write custom membership provider.

I want to write my own Provider class so I can define it in web.config and access it like Membership class.

Here is a sample of my class (it has many other static methods):

```
public static class MySqlHelper
{
    private static string constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnString"].ConnectionString;

    public static int ExecuteNonQuery(string mysqlquery)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(mysqlquery, conn);
    int result;

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        result= cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
    return result;

    }
}
```

Usage: `MySqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery("select * from customers");`

Now as you see I have hard-coded the name of connectionstring i.e. "MyConnString". I am planning to make it dynamic.

So I was wondering if I can make it like static built-in Membership class, where I can define the connectionStringName in web.config. This way the class can be made re-usable without always naming my connectionstring in web.config to "MyConnString".

1: I DON'T want to pass connectionstring in every static method as a parameter.

2: I must be able to access the methods similar to Membership.CreateUser  i.e. static.

I am looking over the web in parallel but any inputs/guidance will help.

**Edited:** I have updated my code sample, to clear some confusion about issues using static class. Here is a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156107/what-are-the-potential-issues-using-this-static-class) I posted to clarify that. Sorry about confusion.

Comment: it seems like your asking for magic or something.  you've basically eliminated 98% of the answers with your qualifications.  you've got to tell the class at some point how to get a connection string.  it can't just divine the information

Comment: @nathan: Take Membership.CreateUser method for example. I can set the connectionStringName in web.config for MembershipProvider to use. Looking for something similar.

Comment: i've updated my answer to take into account your last comment.  i think i may get what you're after now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the only thing i can think of that meets the qualifications you laid out is to use dependency injection, a static constructor, and inject in an something like an `IConnectionStringProvider`.  this seems like about the most convoluted thing i can think of, so you might like it. :)

### edit

after reading your comment, it seems like you just want to be able to reference any connection string, but only one connection string per application.  i'd say just add an element to `appSettings` named `MySqlProviderConnection` with the value being the name of the connection string you want to use.

then in your helper, check for the existence of the appsetting, get its value, and pass it in to your `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` call.  that way your provider could use any connection you want, without changing any code.

Comment: I think the appSettings would do. I will give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

I typically discourage sharing one SqlConnection instance across several requests. Even if you enable [MARS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf1a7f4f%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), you can run into performance issues. I think when your connection receives a non-read command, the connection buffer will pause all current reads until the write finishes. The only thing you're really saving is the time it takes to establish a connection.

SqlConnections are [pooled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) so you can configure the provider to have a min / max number of instances available to soliciting clients. Keep in mind this is also controlled by whatever database you're connecting to; assuming you're connecting to a SQL Server instance, SQL Server has its own maximum connections allowed setting.

Instead of allowing clients to determine when to open/close a shared SqlConnection instance, I suggest having your public members take in either a command string or command parameters. Then, similar to what your sample has suggested, open a connection from the pool and execute the command.

```
public IEnumerable<SqlResults> ExecuteStoredProcedure(string procedure, params SqlParameter[] parameters) {
    using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(MyConnectionStringProperty)) {
        try {
            connection.Open();

            using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(procedure, connection)) {
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                if(parameters != null) {
                    command.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
                }

                // yield return to handle whatever results from proc execution
                // can also consider expanding to support reader.NextResult()
                using(SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader()) {
                    yield return new SqlResults {
                        Reader = reader;
                    };
                }
            }
        }
        finally {
            if(connection.State != ConnectionState.Closed) {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The sample code above is just that - a sample of a concept I use at work. The sample does now have maximized error handling but is very flexible in how results are returned and handled. The `SqlResults` class simply contains a `SqlDataReader` property and can be expanded to include errors.

As far as making any of this `static`, it should be fine as long as you enable a way to make a singleton instance of the provider class and continue to not have any mutable properties be shared (potentially across various requests/threads). You may want to consider some sort of IoC or Dependency Injection approach for providing the connection string given your request.

**EDIT**

Yield allows the caller to use the returned object before the execution context returns to the method yielding the return for continued execution. So in the sample above, a caller can do something like this:

```
// Since it's an IEnumerable we can handle multiple result sets
foreach(SqlResults results in MySqlHelper.ExecuteStoredProcedure(myProcedureName, new SqlParameter("myParamName", myParamValue)) {
    // handle results
}
```

without the connection closing while we handle the results. If you notice in the sample, we have `using` statements for our `SqlClient` objects. This approach allows result set handling to be decoupled from `MySqlHelper` as the provider class will take care of the would-be-duplicate SQL provision code, delegate result handling to the caller, then continue with what it has to do (i.e. close the connection).

As for IoC/DI, I personally use [Castle Windsor](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.MainPage.ashx). You can inject dependency objects as properties or construction parameters. Registering an Inversion of Control container as your dependency resource manager will allow you to (among other things) return the same object when a type of resource is requested. Basically, for every caller class that needs to use `MySqlHelper`, you can inject the same instance when the caller class is instantiated or when the caller class references its public `MySqlHelper` property. I, personally, prefer constructor injection whenever possible. Also, when I say inject, I mean you don't have to worry about setting the property value as your IoC/DI does it for you (if configured properly). See [here](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) for a more in depth explanation.

As another note, the IoC/DI approach would really only come into play if your class is non-static such that each application can have its own singleton instance. If `MySqlHelper` is static, then you could only support one connection string unless you pass it in, which in your original question, you'd prefer not to do so. IoC/DI will allow you to use your `MySqlHelper` property member as if it were static though since the registered container would ensure that the property has a proper instance.

Comment: Thanks. I will plan to incorporate some of the pattern from your sample. Do you mind elaborating on two things: 1: that "yield block". 2: I am going to keep that static part and so wondering any sample on IoC / DI approach you are referring to.

Comment: Thanks @bitxwise. That clears up many things. The main reason I have the class static is I didn't wanted to instantiate my class every now and then. I will have to learn more about IoC/DI. For now I will have to keep my class static and will go with nathan's suggestion. But definitely +1 for your wonderful insight.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete code of a `SqlHelper` that I'd used on some small projects.
But carefull with `static` for this kind of class. If you will use it for Web project, remember that the connection will be shared at the same instance for all users, which can cause bad problems...

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Configuration;

public class SqlHelper
{
    private SqlConnection connection;

    public SqlHelper()
    {
        connection = new SqlConnection();
    }

    public void OpenConnection()
    {
        // Updated code getting the ConnectionString without hard naming it.
        // Yes, if you have more than 1 you'll have problems... But, how many times it happens?

        if (WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.Length == 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("You need to configure the ConnectionString on your Web.config.");
        else
        {
            connection.ConnectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[0].ConnectionString;
            connection.Open();
        }
    }

    public void CloseConnection()
    {
        if (connection != null && connection.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
            connection.Close();
    }

    public DataTable ExecuteToDataTable(string sql)
    {
        DataTable data;

        SqlCommand command = null;
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = null;

        try
        {
            if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                OpenConnection();

            command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
            adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);

            retorno = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(data);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (command != null)
                command.Dispose();

            if (adapter != null)
                adapter.Dispose();

            CloseConnection();
        }

        return data;
    }

    public int ExecuteNonQuery(string sql)
    {
        SqlCommand command = null;

        try
        {
            if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                OpenConnection();

            command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
            return command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (command != null)
                command.Dispose();

            CloseConnection();
        }
    }

    public object ExecuteScalar(string sql)
    {
        SqlCommand command = null;

        try
        {
            if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                OpenConnection();

            command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
            return command.ExecuteScalar();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (command != null)
                command.Dispose();

            CloseConnection();
        }
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
SqlHelper sql = new SqlHelper();
DataTable data = sql.ExecuteToDataTable("SELECT * FROM Customers");
int affected = sql.ExecuteNonQuery("INSERT Customers VALUES ('Test')");
```

But if you really want `static` (if you is on a single user enviroment), just put `static` on all methods.

Comment: while i agree with the don't make the connection static, your code still gets a known connection string from the web.config instead of some magical dynamic method.

Comment: +1 Nice comments about `static` since what the OP asked can cause many troubles and what you answered is much more easy.

Comment: @Erick: Yes, I have similar class but with everything static and using it on more than one websites. No issues so far. The main reason I want to change it is because it has hard-coded connectionStringName (which your class has as well).

Comment: @RickV: I think I will post a new question for discussion on issues with using this class as static.

Comment: @gbs: I updated the code with a simple way of don't hard-coding the connectionStringName. Since you don't have many connections defined on your Web.config, this works fine.

Comment: @gbs: I agree, a new question about it would be nice. But the concept of static itself has the problem that @ErickPetru showed. I think your site haven't get many request at the same second. But be careful.

Comment: @gbs, one last comment: you can also think about [creating your own Configuration Section](http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/032807-1.aspx) for your class. But I really don't belive you'll gain much for need it.

Comment: @EricK: As a matter of fact, I do have two connectionstrings in my web.config. I made the class static so I don't need to instantiate the class every now and then. May be I am wrong due to my less knowledge about static class.