# What are the potential issues using this static class

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, class, static

Here is my sample code:

```
public static class MySqlHelper
{
    private static string constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnString"].ConnectionString;

    public static int ExecuteNonQuery(string mysqlquery)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(mysqlquery, conn);
        int result;

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            result= cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Usage: `MySqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery("select * from customers");`

***I would like to know the issues using this static class.***

I can change my class as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6155650/writing-my-own-provider-class-in-asp-net/6155708#6155708) but I have been using this class in couple of websites and I will need couple days to change it in every place and test it out.

Thanks for any inputs.

**Edit:** Updated the code. Does that make difference on the answers provided? Sorry, I should have posted in the beginning.

Comment: For me, any class named "Helper" qualifies as a [code smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).

Comment: With the new code as shown; add 2 `using` statements - for te command and connection. Always dispose your `IDisposable`s.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am assuming the connection string doesnt change during execution (you might want to make it readonly). Since there is no other shared state shown in the question, there are no real problems.

However, if you have any shared state you have a huge threading problem. And if you have shared *connections* you have an even bigger problem.

But as written, with no significant static fields: no problem.

Comment: I updated my code. What do you think now? From what you said I think my code is fine.

Answer (score 4):

I thought he was pretty clear on his answer.

[Writing my own Provider Class in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6155650/writing-my-own-provider-class-in-asp-net/6155708#6155708)

*"remember that the connection will be shared at the same instance for all users, which can cause bad problems..."*

Comment: Nonetheless there seem to be a few projects using this approach
- http://www.mediachase.com/documentation/fileuploader/Api/Mediachase.FileUploader.SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery_overloads.html
- http://www.extensionmethod.net/Details.aspx?ID=436

Comment: The ConnectionString will be shared amongst all users. SQL connections are *always* shared amongst all users, whether you use static or not. Connections are retrieved from the connection pool; it is a performance optimization which you get for free when using ADO.NET.

Comment: The question ***does not show*** a shared connection. I don't see how this answer applies without that...

Comment: @hemp "always" is wrong in two ways; a: connection pooling is not available for all providers, and b: you can turn it off (it isn't even on-by-default for all). Also, the *underlying* connection might be pooled, but that is different to re-using the managed connection wrapper.

Comment: @Marc: I specified ADO.NET so the [provider argument seems moot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx). However, I'll grant you that it can be disabled, but it's uncommon (I have never worked on a project where it was turned off): "By default, connection pooling is enabled in ADO.NET. Unless you explicitly disable it, the pooler optimizes the connections as they are opened and closed in your application."

Comment: And c: Pooling is transparent to the code, a Connection looks & feels like an ordinary IDisposable.

Comment: @hemp - that is a SQL server document. Yes it is enabled by default for SqlConnection, but ADO.NET is a lot more than that.

Comment: Before we get much further, why does he have two questions? In the link he says, "So I was wondering if I can make it like static". The title of this one is, "What are the potential issues using this static class". This is just a duplicate???

Comment: @Henk I'm not sure how c: is relevant. The answer stated that sharing a connection "can cause bad problems" (sic) - my comment was to clarify that most of the time you are sharing connections whether you know it or not, it's a teaching opportunity. I *suspect* the quoted answer intended to point out that sharing an open connection without calling Close can cause problems, which is valid, but the OPs code is immune as written.

Comment: My point wasn't really to answer this question, but to show that he re-asked the same question. He wasn't satisfied with the answers there, but instead of clarifying his question, he created a new one.

Comment: @Marc wait, you mean people use other database engines with .NET? Sacrilege! Good point: ADO.NET pooling does depend on the connection string and the database provider.

Comment: @Xaade: You are right, I wasn't satisfied, because I never faced any issue with my sites using that code for couple years. I wanted to make sure and have better understanding before I start changing my code. And I would still like to get some answer to my original question in that thread.

Comment: @gbs If you edit your question to clarify what you intend to ask, or to ask additional info, your question should bump up to the top of the question list so more people can see it. So editing your old question would have gotten the same effect as asking a new one. The reason to edit over add, is because now the two questions are dependent on each other for a browsing user to get the full answer to the question. The only reason I don't flag as duplicate, is because the primary question is different enough in my opinion.

Comment: Instead of linking a "root" question, you might better survive if you describe as a new question on the same code sample.

Comment: @Xaade: Thanks. I took out that root reference, to remove any confusion and let this question stand independently.

Answer (score 3):

Static classes are difficult to test.

Your question mentions that for a change you'll have to change the class on a couple websites. If your websites were coupled to an interface, then swapping out the implementation would be relatively simple.

In my own projects I avoid public static classes. They can get unwieldy very quickly.

Answer (score 1):

As such no issue it depends how you are using this class, ideally it part of abstract factory pattern to have static connections so that same connection can be used all over application, but having methods such as executereader and other mthods is not a good choice. similarly always check that connection has not been closed or its state before its usage, because if you are having static connection and you used using syntax with executereader then it will close the connection and if some other method used connection after this then it will get the error

Answer (score 1):

The obvious drawbacks are:

- hardcoded connection string
- without connection pooling in the driver this is very bad: //open conn + //close conn

1) can be ugly solved by using a singleton as the connection string name

2) cannot be solved in a static class without introducing shared data: ie. without planting a knife in your back.

Comment: Yes actually this question came up from that hardcoded connection string. May be if you can give any suggestions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6155650/writing-my-own-provider-class-in-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

Do you know that the MySQL Connector for .NET now has a MySqlHelper class (you can check it in the source [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/))?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to take this route you many want to consider using the Microsoft DAAB SqlHelper v2 offering. It uses the same concept but is much more robust. It also caches SqlParameters. The code came out circa 2001 and has been in constant use by many developers.

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=435