# ExecuteXmlReader and CloseConnection when reader.Close is called

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005, ado.net

I have a static DataAccess class with static methods: MyExecuteReader(returns sqldatareader) and MyExecuteXmlReader (returns XmlReader).

Now with ExecuteReader method I can do SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection) and this will close the connection when I close the reader.

**SqlCommand.ExecuteXmlReader() does not have a similar method.**

So what is the best way in this case to ensure the corresponding connection is closed?

**Note:**

My query returns XML i.e. uses FOR XML AUTO. That is the reason I am using XmlReader. The returned field is considered as SqlString. I can use SqlDataReader.GetSqlString method but I am not sure that is a good approach or not.

**Update:**

I can read the XML into a string and return string instead of XmlReader from the DAL.

I am aware of the using statement and somehow that option was ruled out I believe due to some exception handling issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up modifying the MyExecuteXmlReader (**returns XmlReader**) in my DAL to MyExecuteXmlReader (**returns string**).

So now I am reading from XmlReader to a string and return this string instead of XmlReader and that solves the problem of closing the reader and connection outside of DAL.

Comment: Suggestion: don't use strings to represent XML. If you want to return XML, then return XElement or XDocument.

Comment: Thanks John. We are still using .NET 2.0. I did think of returning as XmlDocument. I don't know why I didn't go that route. Actually with the returned string, I do xmldoc.LoadXml(the returned string) and then read the nodes/elements to populate my class members.  Do you think XML document is fine in this case? and Why not strings?

Comment: If String was the same as XML, then there would be no need for XmlDocument. String and XML do not follow the same rules. Returning a String leads callers to behave like the two are the same, when they're not. Simple example: `<` is valid in a string, but needs special processing in XML, depending on the context. XmlDocument handles this, String does not.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a static DataAccess class with static methods:
>   MyExecuteReader(returns sqldatareader) and MyExecuteXmlReader (returns
>   XmlReader).

This is scary. Only by reading this sentence I must say that having static methods for such things seems just wrong. I would simply rely on the [ADO.NET connection pool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx) and wrap connections into `using` statements. Disposing them doesn't close the connection physically. It simply returns it to the connection pool in order to be reused.

But because you headed this way (using static connections and stuff, rendering your code completely unit testable unfriendly) all I can suggest you is to wrap at least the calls to this `XmlReader` into `using` statements to at least ensure that you release the underlying handles or you will be leaking badly, which in a multithreaded applications could have catastrophic consequences.

Comment: Thanks but I am aware of the static part here is something I started sometime back:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156107/what-are-the-potential-issues-using-this-static-class

Comment: @gbs, I hope it is not too late to get rid of and use proper abstractions with a repository and a data access layer.

Comment: Yes, I should and that is on my list but I am kind of in middle of the sea right now to change that.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the **using** statement.  An example would be:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
  using(SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
  {
     cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ID, Name FROM Customers";

      conn.Open();

      using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
      {
          while (dr.Read())
          {
              // do your thing
          }
      }
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**  Put missing using around SqlCommand

Answer (score 0):

A DataReader reads one row at a time, keeping the connection busy.

An XmlReader reads the result in one go, and does not keep the connection busy.  So there's no need to close it.

Comment: When you'd done with the connection. Your problem is that you were earlier depending on the close behavior and not doing it yourself.

Comment: @John: May be I am misunderstanding. I cannot close the connection before I read from the reader and connection is opened in one class and reader is read in another class. So I don't have access to connection object in second class.

Comment: @gbs: this is why your static method technique is a bad idea.

Answer (score -1):

here is the way to use [more](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

```
[Visual Basic] 
Public Sub ReadMyData(myConnString As String)
    Dim mySelectQuery As String = "SELECT OrderID, CustomerID FROM Orders"
    Dim myConnection As New SqlConnection(myConnString)
    Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand(mySelectQuery, myConnection)
    myConnection.Open()
    Dim myReader As SqlDataReader
    myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader()
    ' Always call Read before accessing data.
    While myReader.Read()
        Console.WriteLine((myReader.GetInt32(0) & ", " & myReader.GetString(1)))
    End While
    ' always call Close when done reading.
    myReader.Close()
    ' Close the connection when done with it.
    myConnection.Close()
End Sub 'ReadMyData

[C#] 
public void ReadMyData(string myConnString) {
    string mySelectQuery = "SELECT OrderID, CustomerID FROM Orders";
    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(myConnString);
    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(mySelectQuery,myConnection);
    myConnection.Open();
    SqlDataReader myReader;
    myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
    // Always call Read before accessing data.
    while (myReader.Read()) {
       Console.WriteLine(myReader.GetInt32(0) + ", " + myReader.GetString(1));
    }
    // always call Close when done reading.
    myReader.Close();
    // Close the connection when done with it.
    myConnection.Close();
 }
```

Comment: did you see the word more and redirect to ms site ?

Comment: How does that affect the fact that the code you posted does not have `using` blocks?